# Django - Uncaught IndentationError while rendering

Tags: python, django

The error occurs in the following line of the template, and I couldn't manage to understand why?

```
In template /usr/local/django/app/templates/main.html, error at line 51

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
```

And the precise error is:

**Caught IndentationError while rendering: unindent does not match any outer indentation level (views.py, line 272)**

The line 272 in views.py is:

```
elif request.POST.get('hiddenField') == 'ad' and SettingsManager.get().ad_integ == 1:
    form = ADSettingsForm(request.POST)  # <-----line 272
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT1**
There is not any indendation errors in any of the files in the project. I controlled it with python's `py_compile` lib.

**UPDATE1**
Alright, this is very, very awkward:
Now, I'm getting whole different error in another machine I have (where I installed a copy of my project)

**Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Could not import wauthportal.wauthapp.views. Error was: No module named views**

```
In template /usr/local/django/wauthadmin/templates/main.html, error at line 51

<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url django.views.i18n.javascript_catalog %}"></script>
```

Comment: Does that line have TAB rather than space for indentation? Or other lines have TAB but this line has spaces?

Comment: do you have the possibility of posting the whole traceback? maybe it is inside of `ADSettingsForm(request.POST)`

Answer (score 1):

This generally happens if you mix up tab and spaces. Please see that you have used four spaces in every indentation. If you are using text editor like Sublime Text pressing ctrl+A will show the spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I used `py_compile` lib to compile `views.py`, and it perfectly compiled - no syntax errors. ;)